# Graphql- How to fetch result based on the condition of a field?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I have a query that look like this:

```
query MyQuery {
  products {
    edges {
      node {
        featured
        id
        image {
          altText
          mediaItemUrl
          slug
        }
        productId
        name
        onSale
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is only fetch the result that `featured` field is `true`, if the `featured` is false, then it never shown in the result.

Something like query like below in mysql:

```
SELECT id,image,name, featured FROM products WHERE featured = 'false'
```

But in graphql query above, I can't query the featured = false.

I tried:

```
query MyQuery {
  products {
    edges {
      node {
        featured @include(if: false)
        id
        ... other field I need
        
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But what this query do is, if `featured` field is true, then included the `featured` field in the result, else don't included the field in the result.This is not what I want.

**What I want is,**

If `featured` field of a product is `true`, then include the `products` into the result, else, remove the whole product from the result.

How can I achieve this in the `MyQuery` above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@include` and `@skip` directives are used for field selection, not filtering. GraphQL has no built-in way of doing filtering, sorting or pagination. It's up to each individual service to implement these features by exposing the appropriate arguments.

In this case, `products` could expose an argument named `filter` or `isFeatured` to add the ability to filter the results by the `featured` value. The field's resolver should then use that argument value to determine the correct value to return.

If you're writing client queries and consuming a schema you did not write, check your API's documentation to determine what arguments are available for the `products` field. If the schema doesn't expose this capability and you don't have a way to change it, then as a client you don't have many options. At best, you can handle the filtering yourself after the result is fetched, but this is troublesome if you also use pagination.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. After seeing your answer I figured out ady. which I realize I can do something like this `products(where: {featured: false}) {.. other stuff } ` . Thanks for your help.